# Is it possible for Dotnet to prioritize a project reference over a nuget?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm working in a huge codebase with a ton of teams. Unfortunately one of the teams is in their own repo (package A) and so we consume their packages through a Nuget. The issue is that this team has a dependency one of the projects in our repo (package B).

What ends up happening when we use package A, it brings in their version of package B. Even if I have a project refence to project B, the version that package A is using gets used. This is causing issues because package A doesn't publish a Nuget constantly, so if package B makes an update, any code that uses package A is forced to use the older code for A.

Is there anyway to get Dotnet/visual studio to just use the project reference version of package B?

Comment: I believe that should work if B were a nuget, too?

Comment: Hi, any update of this issue? Does david's answer answered your question? :)

Comment: yeah, what about that? :)

Answer (score 2):

From your project you can reference the needed package but [excluding its dependecies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#excluding-references):

```
<PackageReference Include="TheOther.Team.Package" Version="12.15.0" ExcludeAssets="All" />
```